# one lab accident away from being

Tags: sentence-structure

[The Big Bang Theory excerpt on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A11MirQw-7Y)

> The guy is one lab accident away from being a super villain.

What is the structure of this sentence? Does it mean:

> The guy is one lab accident

or:

> The guy is a super villain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guy is one lab accident away from being a super villain.
This means that the person is not a super villain yet, but after one lab accident (a lab test maybe), he will be.

Comment: What the sentence means is that "the guy" is either not responsible or not well trained and is in real danger of causing a serious accident by his actions in the laboratory. We use this construction more often by saying things like **one step away disaster...**  https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/141688-what-does-this-mean-quot-one-step-away-from-quot